# Dell XPS 15 9570: Dual Boot with Windows 10 x64 and Ubuntu18.04 amd64

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, 18.04, suspend, dell

**Problem**
Unable to Suspend my laptop. It goes into a half-baked suspend(When triggered from the command line or GUI) resulting in either power drain or comes back up without intervention in a moment.

I have been scouring through posts all over the internet and nothing seems to work.

**System Information:**

*Processor:* Intel® Core™ i9-8950HK CPU @ 2.90GHz × 12

*Graphics:* Intel® HD Graphics (Coffeelake 3x8 GT2)

[I have disabled Nvidia 1050 Ti due to power consumption and
    compatability concerns]

*Kernel:* 4.17.9-041709-generic

**Edit 1:** The System cam with Kernel 4.15, I upgraded Kernel to 4.17 using ukuu in the hopes that the bug might have been fixed upstream.

**Thank you for your consideration, please let me know if you require more information.**

Comment: How's your battery life if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: Gives me between 5-6 hours. I have Nvidia 1050 Ti Disabled and running intel native graphics. Also running at 1080p NOT 4K. But windows gives similar battery life without downgrading specs.

Comment: I get about 7 - 8hrs on intel graphics on my 9570;

Comment: After the recent bios update, my battery life has gone to 8 hours backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrate to Dell xps15 9370 Bios update 1.3.1 recently -- helped with fans and has more than doubled time on battery battery ~9hrs & the Fans aren't going crazy now.

Ed. 9hrs on Intel GPU

following post install from https://github.com/JackHack96/dell-xps-9570-ubuntu-respin

in particular the grub line:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet acpi_rev_override=1 acpi_osi=Linux scsi_mod.use_blk_mq=1 nouveau.modeset=0 nouveau.runpm=0 mem_sleep_default=deep"

​

Dell XPS15 9570, 1.3.1 System BIOS

https://www.dell.com/support/home/uk/en/ukbsdt1/drivers/driversdetails?driverId=82MK9

Intel Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework

https://www.dell.com/support/home/uk/en/ukbsdt1/drivers/driversdetails?driverId=591DK

Comment: Thank you, suspend function working. But when coming out of suspend, wifi no longer shows available networks to connect.

Comment: Also, battery performance has increased significantly. Clocking 9 hours (though it must be noted that I have Nvidia Graphics disabled.

Comment: The battery issue appears to have been solved. So, I will mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I documented it in my blog post here https://medium.com/@pwaterz/how-to-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-18-04-on-the-15-inch-dell-xps-9570-with-nvidia-1050ti-gpu-4b9a2901493d

Specifically you need to disable the nouveau driver via grub:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0 mem_sleep_default=deep nouveau.runpm=0"
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

If that  still doesn't fix it. Do the following:

Open termnal

```
sudo journalctl -f
```

Suspend the laptop -> re open the laptop -> check the log output

This is how I found that the kernel was panicking when trying to sleep the cpu when using the intel graphics.

Kernel panic I saw:

```
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel: Hardware name: Dell Inc. XPS 15 
9570/02MJVY, BIOS 1.3.0 07/12/2018
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel: Workqueue: events_unbound async_run_entry_fn
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel: RIP: 0010:gf100_vmm_flush_+0x15c/0x1a0 [nouveau]
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffa9fc0782f5c8 EFLAGS: 00010282
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel: RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff969a575e0050 RCX: ffffffffaf061dc8
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000096 RDI: 0000000000000246
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel: RBP: ffffa9fc0782f600 R08: 0000086da855788c R09: 000000000000001d
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel: R10: 0000000000000766 R11: 00000000000158a8 R12: ffff969a49d08c00
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel: R13: ffff969a2b5d0f00 R14: 000003cbc7bc6800 R15: ffff969a494a5000
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel: FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff969a5bcc0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel: CR2: 00007f15f4007036 CR3: 00000001b960a004 CR4: 00000000003606e0
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel: Call Trace:
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  gp100_vmm_flush+0x17/0x20 [nouveau]
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  nvkm_vmm_iter.constprop.14+0x323/0x810 [nouveau]
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  ? gp100_vmm_pd0_pde+0x1a0/0x1a0 [nouveau]
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  ? __switch_to_asm+0x40/0x70
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  ? __switch_to_asm+0x40/0x70
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  ? native_sched_clock+0x37/0x90
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  nvkm_vmm_map+0x148/0x400 [nouveau]
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  ? gp100_vmm_pd0_pde+0x1a0/0x1a0 [nouveau]
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  ? __switch_to_asm+0x40/0x70
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  ? __switch_to_asm+0x34/0x70
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  nvkm_vram_map+0x57/0x80 [nouveau]
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  nvkm_uvmm_mthd+0x5ff/0x8d0 [nouveau]
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  nvkm_object_mthd+0x1a/0x30 [nouveau]
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  nvkm_ioctl_mthd+0x65/0x70 [nouveau]
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  nvkm_ioctl+0xe2/0x180 [nouveau]
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  nvkm_client_ioctl+0x12/0x20 [nouveau]
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  nvif_object_ioctl+0x47/0x50 [nouveau]
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  nvif_object_mthd+0x129/0x150 [nouveau]
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  ? _cond_resched+0x19/0x30
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  ? __kmalloc+0x19b/0x230
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  ? nvif_vmm_map+0x3f/0xb0 [nouveau]
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  nvif_vmm_map+0x88/0xb0 [nouveau]
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  nouveau_mem_map+0x82/0xf0 [nouveau]
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  nouveau_vma_map+0x48/0x70 [nouveau]
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  nouveau_bo_move_ntfy+0x77/0xe0 [nouveau]
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  ttm_bo_handle_move_mem+0x2d2/0x520 [ttm]
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  ttm_bo_evict+0x142/0x1c0 [ttm]
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  ? drm_edid_to_sad+0x194/0x1d0 [drm]
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  ttm_mem_evict_first+0x19a/0x220 [ttm]
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  ttm_bo_force_list_clean+0xa1/0x170 [ttm]
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  ttm_bo_evict_mm+0x2e/0x30 [ttm]
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  nouveau_do_suspend+0x85/0x2d0 [nouveau]
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  nouveau_pmops_suspend+0x39/0x80 [nouveau]
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  pci_pm_suspend+0x76/0x130
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  ? pci_pm_freeze+0xf0/0xf0
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  dpm_run_callback+0x5b/0x130
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  __device_suspend+0x109/0x450
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  async_suspend+0x1f/0x90
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  async_run_entry_fn+0x3c/0x150
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  process_one_work+0x1f5/0x3c0
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  worker_thread+0x32/0x400
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  kthread+0x120/0x140
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  ? pwq_unbound_release_workfn+0xd0/0xd0
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  ? kthread_bind+0x40/0x40
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel:  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel: Code: 41 5e 41 5f 5d c3 49 8b 7c 24 10 48 8b 5f 50 48 85 db 74 4d e8 56 4a 3c ed 48 89 da 48 c7 c7 9c a8 f9 c0 48 89 c6 e8 b6 79 de ec <0f> 0b eb bf 49 8b 7c 24 10 48 8b 5f 50 48 85 db 74 1e e8 2d 4a 
Aug 08 19:20:26 hermes kernel: ---[ end trace ff7d3fd86666433f ]---
```

Comment: What would it output if there was a kernel panic with regards to intel graphics while sleeping?

Comment: I updated my response with the kernel panic log.

Comment: My laptop isn't giving these results. But thanks for the help man! I will keep a look out for this problem.

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to try to simplify the answer, which has been provided in other threads but a bit hard to come by in a straight forward form.

A lot of people are dealing with suspend issues in Ubuntu nowadays. The problem is baked into 18.04 at the moment. Here is the solution:

Open up `/etc/default/grub` in a text editor. For example:
`sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

At the line that starts with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, after the equals sign and inside the quotation marks, add the command `scsi_mod.scan=sync`

Then try suspend again, it should work. It did for me at least.

Comment: My answer is the "how" to fix it part. For information on "why" this fix is necessary, see this bug report here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1776887

Comment: Made changes, Rebooted, tried to suspend. Same issue. The system doesn't go into suspend and jumps back up.[Simply logs me out] Thank you for your time. :)

Comment: Do you recommend downgrading to one of the pre bug mainline kernels ?

Comment: thank you for actually trying my solution! And I would recommend simply attempting to use one of the previous kernels and seeing if that fixes it, but no need to bother downgrading. Next time you start up your PC and it loads into the grub menu (the startup selector for Ubuntu, Windows 10, etc), go to advanced options for ubuntu and try booting with one of the older available kernels (if you have any) and see if that fixes it. If it does, then probably consider a downgrade.

Comment: Tried Kernel 4.14, similar issues of freezing while going into suspend.